# Excessive memory problem in tensorflow model reloaded for cross-validation

Tags: python, tensorflow, kernel

I am having an excessive memory load in the script below since I reload the tensorflow model and run these models for the cross validation for about 100 rows. After each scenario after each loop the job is getting slower and finally the memory reaches above 95%. "tf.keras.backend.clear_session()" doesn't work in the loops.

I need to restart kernel for each scenario. How to do that?

```
for sc in scenarios:
     ...
                                    
     for f in os.scandir(mypath):
         if f.is_dir() and f.name.startswith('swish') or f.name.startswith('elu') or f.name.startswith('gelu'):
             model_name=str(f.name)
             tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
             for mm in range(0,108,1):
                 sl=0
                 for i in X.index:
                         tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
                         X_train=X[X.index!=i]
                         X_test=X[X.index==i]
                         y_train=y[y.index!=i]
                         y_test=y[y.index==i]
                         model=tf.keras.models.load_model(mypath + "/" + model_name + '/model_' +
                                                           str(mm+1) +  ".h5")
```